# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in a Symfony project using Webpack Encore

Tags: jquery, symfony, responsive-design, webpack-encore, revolution-slider

[Error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOsg7.png)

Hello,

I am a beginner in programming and I'm working on a Symfony project using Webpack Encore to manage my assets. I am facing an issue with jQuery in my Firefox console: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

Here's the App.js file content:

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
import './styles/app.scss';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';

const $ = require('jquery');
// this "modifies" the jquery module: adding behavior to it
// the bootstrap module doesn't export/return anything

// importer sur le js de bootstrap https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html#importing-bootstrap-javascript
require('bootstrap');

require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js');

// import JS de revolution slider
import './custom/js/rs6.js';

/**
 * help for import Js with webpack
 */

setREVStartSize({ c: 'rev_slider_1_1', rl: [1240, 1024, 778, 480], el: [800, 550, 500, 450], gw: [1390, 1024, 778, 480], gh: [800, 550, 500, 450], type: 'standard', justify: '', layout: 'fullwidth', mh: "0" });
var revapi1,
  tpj;
function revinit_revslider11() {
  $(function () {
    tpj = jQuery;
    revapi1 = tpj("#rev_slider_1_1");
    if (revapi1 == undefined || revapi1.revolution == undefined) {
      revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("rev_slider_1_1");
    } else {
      revapi1.revolution({
        sliderLayout: "fullwidth",
        visibilityLevels: "1240,1024,778,480",
        gridwidth: "1390,1024,778,480",
        gridheight: "800,550,500,450",
        spinner: "spinner0",
        perspectiveType: "local",
        keepBPHeight: true,
        editorheight: "800,550,500,450",
        responsiveLevels: "1240,1024,778,480",
        progressBar: { disableProgressBar: true },
        navigation: {
          onHoverStop: false
        },
        fallbacks: {
          allowHTML5AutoPlayOnAndroid: true
        },
      });
    }

  });
} // End of RevInitScript
var once_revslider11 = false;
if (document.readyState === "loading") { document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () { if ((document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") && !once_revslider11) { once_revslider11 = true; revinit_revslider11(); } }); } else { once_revslider11 = true; revinit_revslider11(); }
```

As a beginner, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me identify the cause of this error and how to resolve it. Thanks in advance!

I was trying to **load the JavaScript** for **Revolution Slider** in order to make the slider responsive across all necessary screen formats.

I expected the slider to automatically adjust its size and layout based on the screen size and resolution of the device it is being viewed on. However, due to the **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined** error, the slider is not functioning as intended, and I am unable to achieve the desired responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring jquery and you assign it to the $ const. The jQuery object is not imported automatically. So to fix your issue, either:

`const $ = jQuery = require('jquery');`

or change `tpj = jQuery;` to `tpj = $;`